# Can't get current value from an array using $.each() iterator function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a simple todo app with Jquery.
However trying to display current value when I hit the add button seems to produce an anomaly, i.e all array item is displayed when the add button is clicked. 
I have included a snippet of my code below. I followed the steps I saw here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

```js
var inputVal = $('#formField').val()
var todoList = $('#todolist');


var todos = [];
function createTodo(item){
// Return a todo object
}

function removeTodo(index){
    // Remove todo from todos at index
}

function addTodo(todo){
//Add todo to todos

todos.unshift($('#formField').val())
}

function renderTodos(){
    $.each(todos, function( index, value ) {
        $('.todolist').prepend(`<li> ${value}<span class delete> X </span> </li>`);
      });
}

$('#subBut').click(function (e) { 
    
    addTodo(inputVal);
    renderTodos()
    
});
```

```css
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  ol {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>ToDo App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <h2>My Todo App</h2>
        <div id="taskForm">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a task" id="formField">
            <input type="button" id="subBut" value="Add">
        </div>
       
    </div>
  
    <div id="result">
            <ol class="todolist">
                
            </ol>
        </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/script/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just prepend the new input, you don't need the `$.each`.

```js
var inputVal = "";
var todoList = $('#todolist');


var todos = [];
function createTodo(item){
// Return a todo object
}

function removeTodo(index){
    // Remove todo from todos at index
}

function addTodo(todo){
//Add todo to todos

    todos.unshift(inputVal);
}

function renderTodos(){
    $('.todolist').prepend(`<li> ${inputVal}<span class delete> X </span> </li>`);
    
}

$('#subBut').click(function (e) { 
    inputVal = $('#formField').val();
    addTodo(inputVal);
    renderTodos();
    
});
```

```css
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  ol {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>ToDo App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <h2>My Todo App</h2>
        <div id="taskForm">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a task" id="formField">
            <input type="button" id="subBut" value="Add">
        </div>
       
    </div>
  
    <div id="result">
            <ol class="todolist">
                
            </ol>
        </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/script/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or you could add that line to the addTodo function and leave the renderTodos as it is. It might be useful later on if you fetch the initial list from the backend or similar.

Answer (score 3):

The `.todolist` already contains some items and you are trying to prepend all the items again, that's why you are getting duplicates. You could clear the `.todolist` using `.empty()` before prepending again

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the expected behavior of `each()`. It iterates over each item of the array. Then you prepend all items to the list. Every time the whole list.

So you can either remove the elements from the list before you prepend the list again or just add the new item. Hope this helps!